# generating a list with images picked from gallery or camera using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im using react native and hooks with the library react-native-image-crop-picker to make a view where i choose from taking a photo with my camera or open my cellphone gallery and chose any image i want, once i have a picture it should show the image in a list, so if i choose more than one picture it should show more than oneimage in the list.

so far this code can open the gallery and it can take photos, the console log shows that it takes the image, but i canot render the image in the list, can i have some help?

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';

const Seleccion = ({navigation}) => {
  const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);
  const state = useMemo(() => ({ fileList }), [fileList]);

  const onSelectedImage = useCallback((image) => {
    setFileList(fileList => {
      const newDataImg = [...fileList];
      const source = { uri: image.path };
      const item = {
        id: Date.now(),
        url: source,
        content: image.data
      };
      newDataImg.push(item);
      return newDataImg;
    });
  }, [setFileList]);

  const takePhotoFromCamera = useCallback(() => {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
    }).then(image => {
      onSelectedImage(image);
      console.log(image);
    });
  }, [onSelectedImage]);

  const choosePhotoFromLibrary = useCallback(() => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
    }).then(image => {
      onSelectedImage(image);
      console.log(image);
    });
  }, [onSelectedImage]);

  const renderItem = useCallback(({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={item.url} style={styles.itemImage} />
      </View>
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={fileList}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        extraData={state}
      />

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.viewData} onPress={takePhotoFromCamera}>
        <Text>Foto</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.viewData} onPress={choosePhotoFromLibrary}>
        <Text>galeria</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const resizeMode = 'center';

Seleccion.navigationOptions = {
  headerShown: false,
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#333333',
  },
  container2: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  textContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  textIniciar: {
    color: 'white',
    width: 300,
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  back: {
    marginTop: 30,
    marginLeft: 20,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    color: 'white',
  },
  textInit: {
    marginTop: 30,
    color: '#b3b4b5',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    marginTop: 100,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  viewData: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 20,
    width: 260,
    borderRadius: 30,
    height: 45,
    backgroundColor: '#D32345',
  },
  logout: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    width: 260,
    borderRadius: 30,
    height: 45,
    backgroundColor: '#911830',
  },
  loginText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't defined the `itemImage` object in your styles. add this to your styles object and it should work

```
itemImage: {
      height: 200,
      width: 200
  }
```